# Ошибка ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Tags: python

Добрый вечер, помогите решить проблему

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver_sandbox.py", line 11, in
>      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101
>   5.0\src\debug\tserver_sandbox.py", line 3, in f
>       pass builtins.ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Код:

```
def f(x):
    f=1/abs((x-3)**3)
    return f
a=2.0
b=4.0
print('e=')
e = float(input())
c=(a+b)/2
while abs(b-a)>e:
    if f(a)*f(c)<0:
        b=c
    else:
        a=c
        c=(a+b)/2
x=(a+b)/2
print('x=',x,'f(x)=',f(x))
```

Ошибка во второй строке f=1/abs((x-3)**3), не пойму как её решить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У функции `f(x)` есть запрещённый аргумент - 3 (при нём происходит деление на 0). Именно 3 получается в `c` в 8-й строке, а в 10-й это `c` равное запретной тройке передаётся в функцию `f(x)`.